# how to get VMware folder from cli

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, vmware

I am writing an ansible script to shutdown several VM's when they are not needed.  I am able to do that when I know where the VM lives.  The problem is that the VM could move around to different folders if it vmotions to a different host.  According to the article below I need to know the folder of the VM which again could change.  Not sure how to get the folder automatically.  Is there a way to do this with Ansible and or Python then feed it into the script?

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/vmware_guest_powerstate_module.html

```
- name: Set the state of a virtual machine to poweroff
  vmware_guest_powerstate:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    validate_certs: no
    folder: "/{{ datacenter_name }}/vm/my_folder"
    name: "{{ guest_name }}"
    state: powered-off
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: deploy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get information about the VM using [vmware_guest_info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/vmware_guest_info_module.html) module and then pass the folder in the next task like so,

```
- name: Gather info about the vmware guest vm
  vmware_guest_info:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
    validate_certs: no
    name: "{{ guest_name }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: vm_info



- name: Set the state of a virtual machine to poweroff
  vmware_guest_powerstate:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    validate_certs: no
    folder: "{{ vm_info['hw_folder']}}"
    name: "{{ guest_name }}"
    state: powered-off
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: deploy
```